# Move /var/lib/readarr folder to different location

Tags: filesystem, compute-module-4

I'm stumped. I'm trying to run Readarr (`https://wiki.servarr.com/en/readarr`) on a Raspberry Pi NAS that only has 8 GB of internal (mmc) storage but two larger SSDs for data. When I populate the Readarr database, the data is stored `/var/lib/readarr` and quickly fills up the mmc-storage so that the RPi stops working. How can I move this folder to a different location?

I tired using `sudo ln -s /srv/mergerfs/PiBoxShare/sys/readarr/ /var/lib/readarr` after moving the data that was in `var/lib/readarr` to the PiBoxShare... But Readarr stopped working after that.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [bind mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/659113/25985).  Makes sure readarr isn't running first and:

```
sudo mount --bind /srv/mergerfs/PiBoxShare/sys/readarr/ /var/lib/readarr
```

You should also find out if readarr (I am not familiar with it) logs errors so you can further determine why it "stopped working".

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Sadly, this yielded the same result. The only way I know to find logs is via the services website ('http://localhost:8787'). This site is unreachable when the files are moved from their original location.

Comment: Running: `sudo systemctl status readarr`yields the following output after moving the folder and binding it:
systemd[1]: Started Readarr Daemon.
Readarr[360582]: [Info] Bootstrap: Starting Readarr - /opt/Readarr/Readarr.dll - Version 0.1.4.1596
Readarr[360582]: [Debug] Bootstrap: Getting windows service status
Readarr[360582]: [Info] AppFolderInfo: Data directory is being overridden to [/var/lib/readarr]
Readarr[360582]: [Debug] Bootstrap: Console selected
Readarr[360582]: [Info] AppFolderInfo: Data directory is being overridden to [/var/lib/readarr]

Comment: Readarr[360582]: [Trace] EventAggregator: Publishing ApplicationStartingEvent
Readarr[360582]: [Info] AppFolderInfo: Data directory is being overridden to [/var/lib/readarr]
Readarr[360582]: [Info] MigrationController: *** Migrating data source=/var/lib/readarr/readarr.db;cache size=-10000;datetimekind=Utc;journal mode=Wal;pooling=True;ve>
Readarr[360582]: [Debug] MigrationController: Took: 00:00:00.7813305

Comment: Is there stuff in that directory that it leaves behind when it stops?  If so I presume you made sure it would be there when it starts again... Also you might look into whether that directory can be set in some configuration.  Glancing at this: https://wiki.servarr.com/radarr/appdata-directory I'd guess the reason it is using that directory is because the user it is running as has no home.  Presuming it isn't running root, you should be sure the permissions are what you think they are when the directory is symlinked or bind mounted.

Comment: Something I've done with apps that are occasionally prone to dumping ridiculous amounts of data in a short period is mounting a file on the data directory; [this is the procedure](https://askubuntu.com/a/1256439/239729) although you should use ext4, that is a bit dated.  Anyway, the point is this way you can easily place a hard limit on how much space it uses...

Comment: ...It probably won't solve this particular problem though, because I'm sure the issue isn't that readarr finds its data dir is a mount or symlink and then goes, "Won't do that!".   It would be absurd; at best someone maybe thinks that is a security measure (but I doubt it).  So the problem is some nuance like permissions or missing data. **You should try and ask about this via their support on discord or reddit, post a link to this question and someone will surely spot the problem in short order.**